# CSS Text positioning

Tags: css, text, alignment

I have a container and I have #info holding my h5 text. How can I position the text anywhere i want within the container without messing the page up when the resolution is different. Thanks.

```
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

    body {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    }

    #container {
    background-image:url('pic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 541px;
    width:1020px;
    margin: auto;
    }

    #info {
    height:500px;
    width:700px;
    }

    a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    }
    a:hover {
    background-color:#efefef;
    } 

    h5 {
    color:black;
    font-size:0.9em;
    }

   </style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not messing the page up"? If possible give an example of what you're trying to achieve, even if that is an image it would help folk trying to help, visualise what you're trying to do.

Comment: okay.  so the resolution is in 1440x900 and it is changed to 1024x768, the text moves and is in a different part of the container. How do I get it to "stick"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `#container` and to `h5`. Then you can move the headline with `left` and `top` (or `right` and `bottom`).

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}


h5 {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/4b9xK/